# Make ListView ignore rightclick totally

Tags: wpf, listview

I'am just coding some global gesture handlers for a wpf application. For example I am supposed to use right click as a trigger to proceed UI.

```
<Window.InputBindings>
        <MouseBinding MouseAction="RightClick" Command="NavigationCommands.NextPage"/>
</Window.InputBindings>
```

But now the problem appears that `<ListBox/>` consumes all mouse button events. I did some research but didn't found an easy way to make it just be unaware of the right button. Did anybody ever had this problem and found a solution? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to prevent the ListBox from consuming the mouse clicks using the following:

```
<ListBox>
        <ListBox.InputBindings>
            <MouseBinding MouseAction="RightClick" Command="ApplicationCommands.NotACommand" />
        </ListBox.InputBindings>
    </ListBox>
```

Comment: How sure are you that your command isn't being executed?  In my simple example (below - sorry about the formatting!) my event handler is invoked correctly when I right click on my listbox.

<Window.CommandBindings>
        <CommandBinding Command="NavigationCommands.NextPage" Executed="CommandBinding_Executed" />
    </Window.CommandBindings>
    <Window.InputBindings>
        <MouseBinding MouseAction="RightClick" Command="NavigationCommands.NextPage" />
    </Window.InputBindings>
    <Grid>
        <ListBox Background="Red" />
    </Grid>